# A simple problem regarding continuity.

Tags: analysis

**Suppose that f and g are 1-1 on R. If f and g◦f are continuous on R, then g is continuous on R.**

The answer is false, according to the solution, but I can't see why..

My initial reasoning was this :

---

Let h := g◦f. By the hypothesis, h is continuous.

Also, since f is 1-1 and continuous on R, $f^-1$ is defined and continuous on R.

Hence, h◦$f^-1$ is defined on R, and continuous on R (by the composite property of continuity).

Therefore, g = h◦$f^-1$ is continuous on R.

---

Where does my reasoning go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Take $f(x) =x^2$ and $g(x)=|x|$ , $g(x)$ is discontinuous at x=0 because the left and right limits are not the same

Comment: How are either of $f$ and $g$ one-one?

Comment: Thanks CivilSigma, but I suspect what you are talking about is differentiability, as well as f and g is not 1-1.

Comment: @CivilSigma neither $|x|$ nor $x^2$ is 1-1

Comment: Oh sorry, I confused what 1-1 meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the range of $f$. If Range $f \in$ Domain $g$, then $g◦f$ is continuous. However, Range $f$ is not necessarily the whole Domain of $g$. So for any value $x \in$ Domain $g$ and $x$ not in Range $f$, $g$ could be 1-1 and not continuous.

Comment: @ATP Yeah, I was puzzled at first too. NP